# Snowflake:Automate Cloning Process

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement: I am looking at how to automate the cloning process from Prod to dev every day

Either Python or Stored Procedure

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you create any python code or stored procedure? Did you encounter any specific issue? Your question is too broad

Answer (score 1):

You can clone a database with a single-line SQL statement; however, I tested running that in a SQL stored procedure and it will not run create statements in SQL stored procedures. A JavaScript stored procedure will work.

Since all Snowflake tasks require a stored procedure to run, you'll need a JavaScript stored procedure if you want to use tasks.

Here's a sample:

```
-- Recommend you do not store the SP in a database you'll be cloning
create or replace procedure UTIL_DB.PUBLIC.CLONE_MY_DB()
returns string
language javascript
as
$$

return executeNonQuery('create or replace database TEST2 clone TEST1');

function executeNonQuery(queryString) {
    var out;
    cmd1 = {sqlText: queryString};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue('status');
    return out;
};

$$;

-- Make sure the SP works
drop database if exists TEST2;
call UTIL_DB.PUBLIC.CLONE_MY_DB();

-- Create a task calling the SP.
-- Use CRON syntax to get productionized
-- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html
create task MY_CLONE_TASK
    warehouse = TEST
    schedule = '1440 minute'
as call UTIL_DB.PUBLIC.CLONE_MY_DB();
```

Remember that your task is not enabled by default. You'll need to do something like this for the role you want to run the task:

```
use role ACCOUNTADMIN;
grant execute task on account to role SYSADMIN;
use role SYSADMIN;

alter task UTIL_DB.PUBLIC.MY_CLONE_TASK resume;
```

Comment: Thanks, Interesting, I will check on this. Does every cloning incur a cost?

Answer (score 0):

Since you make reference to cloning, I will assume that your Prod and Dev environments are in the same Snowflake account.  You could this pretty easily with a task that simply drops the DEV database and then clones the PROD database.  I don't think you need an SP or Python for this.